# How to "Copy to Sheet" only if file exists

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So here is my problem, I have a script for copying a bunch of independent one sheet google spreadsheets into one **master spreadsheet** as tabs, but because I'm using "title contains" it creates sheets (tabs) for non existent spreadsheets (in the example below: it will make "ADC Lunch" even though that sheet doesn't exist). I have about 50 of these in a script, what is the best way to ensure that only the sheets that have actual spreadsheet files correspondent to their name exist in my **master spreadsheet**? I was thinking maybe a "if then" like IF(ID=true, sheet.copyTo(destination).setName("ADC Breakfast")) but I don't have much experience in api script yet so I don't know how to formulate it around this function. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Illustration:

1. "Spreadsheet 1"
2. "Spreadsheet 2" --> compiled --> Master Spreadsheet (with 3 sheets)
3. "Spreadsheet 3"

Problem:

Master Spreadsheet searches for Spreadsheet X by "title contains" search, if it doesn't find one of the spreadsheets with the specific requirements, it just copies another spreadsheet that is close enough into the master spreadsheet as Spreadsheet X. How can I make it so it will only copy a spreadsheet to the master spreadsheet (as a tab) if it actually exists and fulfills the "title contains" parameters? I hope this clarifies things, sorry for my poor description.

```
function ArrayBuilder() {
    var filesource = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "ADC Breakfast" and parents in "File_ID"');
    while(filesource.hasNext()){
        var File = filesource.next();
        var ID = File.getId();
    }
    var name = File.getName()
    var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID);
    var sheet = source.getSheets()[0];
    var destinationID = "File_ID";
    var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationID);

     sheet.copyTo(destination).setName("ADC Breakfast");
```

Comment: Can you explain about `Illustration:` and your current script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finding Spreadsheets that have only one sheet**

I know this isn't the answer to your question but perhaps it will help you think about it another way.  This function finds Spreadsheets that only have 1 sheet and it appends the file name, file id and sheet name to a spreadsheet.  It also adds an extension to the file name like (n) where n is an integer indicating how many files have had that name.  With the information in the spreadsheet you could probably figure out which ones you would like to copy into your master spreadsheet or if you wish assistance in modifying it please let me know.

```
function findSpreadsheetsWithOnlyOneSheet() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('File Data Sheet');
  var nA=[];
  var nObj={};
  var files=DriveApp.getFolderById('Folder Id').getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file=files.next();
    var id=file.getId();
    var name=file.getName();
    if(Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(id).sheets.length==1) {
      var sheetname=Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(file.getId()).sheets[0].properties.title;
      if(nA) {
        if(nA.indexOf(name)==-1) {
          nA.push(name);
          sh.appendRow([name,id,sheetname]);
        }else{
          if(nObj.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            nObj[name]+=1;
          }else{
            nObj[name]=1;
          }
          sh.appendRow([name + '(' + nObj[name] + ')',id,sheetname])
        }
      }else{
        sh.appendRow([name,id,sheetname]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is what my spreadsheet looks like:

[image]

[Sheets API version 4](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest)

[DriveApp Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app)